# How to authenticate request using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Here is the XHR cURL data:

```
curl "http://example.com/stream/contents?streamId=user"%"2FmyId"%"2Fcategory"%"2Fapple&count=40&ranked=newest" -H
     "Cookie: large-cookie-data" -H
     "$Authorization.example: $ExampleAuth" -H
     "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H
     "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H
     "Authorization: OAuth veryLargeRandomKey:example" -H
     "Content-Type: application/json" -H
     "Accept: */*" -H
     "Referer: http://example.com/somepage" -H
     "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36" -H
     "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed
```

I am using the following PHP code:

```
$c = curl_init('http://example.com/streams/contents?streamId=user"%"2F3ad1e06d-e1ac-49b4-ae99-21f96b2af86f"%"2Fcategory"%"2Fapple&count=40&ranked=newest');                 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'Big cookie string here');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/page/');
$z = curl_getinfo($c);
$s = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

The first error that I got was `missing streamId key`. Now, I guessed this is because of `"%"` in the URL so I replaced them with `%`. After that, I got the error `unauthorized access: not logged in`. 
So, I tried to add one more option to `CURLOPT`. The option I added was `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTHORIZATION, 'OAuth veryLargeRandomKey:example');`. I had no reason to believe that it will work and it didn't. The error I got was

`Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_AUTHORIZATION - assumed 'CURLOPT_AUTHORIZATION'`

I have removed this extra option now. My question is how can I successfully authenticate my request. If you need any other information please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know which of those headers are actually required for authentication. And then add them like this:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    '$Authorization.example: $ExampleAuth',
    'Authorization: OAuth veryLargeRandomKey:example'
));
```

`CURLOPT_AUTHORIZATION` constant doesn't exist, for the list of usable constants see [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: Thank you very much, buddy :).

I thought each of these options will have their own `CURLOPT` constants. Can I also put all the headers like `useragent` etc. in the HTTPHEADER constant or do they need to go with their own constant headers?

Comment: Yes, you can, but using their dedicated constants makes code clearer (in my opinion). You are welcome)